# New MacBook Pro can't connect to Internet

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, macbook-pro

As the tile says I recently got a new Mac.  It is the latest gen retina display with a dual core i5 and 8 GB or RAM.  It has the latest "ac/b/g/n" WiFi adapter but it is connecting to an "n" network.  When I was setting it up, it was unable to connect to the Internet connection all my other devices (computer, iPad etc.) were using successfully.

When it tries to connect, it shows the wireless icon as connected, but it has an exclamation point in it.  When you look under the network preferences, it says "Wi-Fi does not have an IP address, can't connect".  I have tried this on other networks and it has shown the same error.

I have looked on Google but couldn't find a solution.  It appears it might be an issue with the Mac not having an IP address assigned to it.  It might be a factory defect etc.

If you know anything about this issue all help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to a different network? Can you connect using an ethernet cable?

Comment: I mentioned in the post that I have tried it on other networks unsuccessfully.  I don't have ethernet just wireless.

Comment: Pardon me, I missed the part with connecting to other networks. What model router do you have? I'd be very surprised if it doesn't have ethernet ports on it, unless you're talking about the Macbook.

Comment: It probably does but we don't have cables for it etc.

Comment: Does your wifi network have MAC address filtering enabled?

Comment: How would I check that?  My other devices work but the Mac doesn't.

Comment: If it's new and it never worked, take it back and get it checked under warranty.

Comment: OK, probably am going to do that.